# How can I change width of sentence in ASP.NET Core project?

Tags: html, css, fonts

I have an ASP.NET Core project. I want to decrease or increase width of a sentence. I use a CSS class and set `font-stretch` style, but it doesn't work. Is there another way to do this?

For example:

```
.font-expanded {
  font-stretch: expanded !important;
}

.font-condensed {
  font-stretch: condensed !important;
}

<p>
      Hello Students
</p>
<p class="font-expanded">
      Hello Students
</p>
<p class="font-condensed">
      Hello Students
</p>
```

It doesn't work and three paragraphs have same width in browser...

Comment: Pls. Show us some code

Comment: @DanielStackenland example added!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe [letter-spacing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/letter-spacing) is what you are searching for:

```css
.font-expanded {
  letter-spacing: 5px;
}

.font-condensed {
  letter-spacing: -1px;
}
```

```html
<p>
      Hello Students
</p>
<p class="font-expanded">
      Hello Students
</p>
<p class="font-condensed">
      Hello Students
</p>
```

The `font-stretch` property only selects different font-faces from your font. It doesn't style the text directly ([as mentioned in the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-stretch)). If your font had different font faces for these values, then the property should work as expected.